# Is there a way to find the important commits in GIT before a release?

Tags: github, gitlab, git-commit, git-diff

As in not only the major changes maybe the installed dependencies and all before a release without checking one by one?

Comment: All along the way you could tag those important commits with something which you could search for later on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since Git won't know which commits are *important* to you, you'll have to first define your own set of guidelines/format on how you write your commit messages, which you can then use later on to easily differentiate all the commits made for a particular development period.

For example:

- If it's a bug fix, prepend the commit message with a "**[bugfix]**"
- If it's a new feature, prepend the commit message with a "**[feature]**"
- If it's a project setup change, prepend the commit message with a "**[migration]**"

Then, once all the branches have been merged to the main branch (let's say it's **develop**), checkout the **develop** branch and use [`git log --grep=<PATTERN>`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log#git-log---grepltpatterngt) to identify a specific set of commits.

For example, if you only need the bug fix commits, do a:

> `git log --grep="bugfix"`

which will show you all the commits with "**bugfix**" in the commit message.

If you only need the commits for a specific period, you can use the [`--since=<date>`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log#git-log---sinceltdategt) option:

> `git log --since="2017-06-01" --grep="bugfix"`

If you want a formatted list (something that you can easily output to some sort of release notes, I assume), you can use the [`--format=<format>`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log#git-log---formatltformatgt) option:

> `git log --since="2017-06-01" --grep="bugfix" --format="(%ci) %h : %s"`

The command above will give you something like this:

> ```
> (2017-06-18 18:26:36 +0800) 63f330f : [bugfix] prevent crash when dialog is sent to background
> (2017-07-01 10:03:40 +0800) cdcbd91 : [bugfix] remove extra row at the end of the list
> ```

You can check out the [other format options](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log#_pretty_formats) from the complete [`git log docs`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log).

Basically, it will all depend on your commit message format.
As a tip, you can look into using a [`commit.template`](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Configuration) to make it easier to format your commit messages.

> `commit.template`
>
> If you set this to the path of a file on your system,
>   Git will use that file as the default message when you commit. For
>   instance, suppose you create a template file at `~/.gitmessage.txt` that
>   looks like this:
>
> `subject line`
>
> `what happened`
>
> `[ticket: X]`